# Linq to entity performance issues with large set of data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am currently working with EF4 and in one of my scenario i am using join and wanted to retrieve the data but as the resultant data is so much EF4 is even fail to generate the query plan..As a work around i tried to load the data in simple generic list( using Selecting all data from both the tables) and then tried to join on that two list but still i am getting outofmemory exception as one table contains around 100k records and second table contains 50k records i wanted to join them in query...but still with noluck using EF...please suggest me any work around of this...

Comment: Use standard measurements. Most people don't know what a lack is.

Comment: Are you doing anything to limit the result set?

Comment: sorry if i have created any confusion...but one of my table contains 100000 and second table has around 50000 records....

Comment: @Aducci : no currently not, how can i if wanted to join these two large tables using linq to entityframework?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any scenario where you would *need* a result set containing 100k+ records. It may not be the answer you want, but the best way to improve performance is to reduce the amount of records that you're dealing with.

Comment: this is the scenario with which i am struggling...how can i restrict my table records participating in the join and get the expected result that i am not getting...i know the problem is due to the large amount of data is involved that EF can not handle...but i am asking about any work around of this problem in linq to entityframework...

Comment: I would update your question and explain what you're trying to do with these records. What are you using them for?

Comment: I just want to join these two tables and wanted to have the result but the problem is the amount of data involved in the join is very large..

Comment: you've made it pretty clear that you just want the data, but why do you need ALL of it ? what are you trying to do with it? like @JamesJohnson said, i can't imagine why you would need 100 k records.
edit: are you trying to join the 2 tables to put the combined data in some table or xml-file or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

What we did is that we wrote custom SQL and executed it with Context.Database.SqlQuery(sql, params)